# Equivalent of arcpy.Statistics_analysis using NumPy (or other)

Tags: python, numpy, arcpy

I am having a problem (I think memory related) when trying to do an `arcpy.Statistics_analysis` on an approximately 40 million row table. I am trying to count the number of non-null values in various columns of the table per category (e.g. there are x non-null values in column 1 for category A). After this, I need to join the statistics results to the input table.

Is there a way of doing this using numpy (or something else)?

The code I currently have is like this:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(input_layer, output_layer, "'Column1' COUNT; 'Column2' COUNT; 'Column3' COUNT", "Categories")
```

I am very much a novice with arcpy/numpy so any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a table to a numpy array using the function [arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.4/analyze/arcpy-data-access/tabletonumpyarray.htm). And then convert the array to a `pandas.DataFrame` object.

Here is an example of code (I assume you are working with Feature Class because you use the term null values, if you work with shapefile you will need to change the code as null values are not supported are replaced with a single space string (`' '`):

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

# Change these values
gdb_path = 'path/to/your/geodatabase.gdb'
table_name = 'your_table_name'
cat_field = 'Categorie'
fields = ['Column1','column2','Column3','Column4']

# Do not change
null_value = -9999 
input_table = gdb_path + '\\' + table_name

# Convert to pandas DataFrame
array = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(input_table, 
                                   [cat_field] + fields, 
                                   skip_nulls=False, 
                                   null_value=null_value)
df = pd.DataFrame(array)

# Count number of non null values
not_null_count = {field: {cat: 0 for cat in df[cat_field].unique()} 
                  for field in fields}
for cat in df[cat_field].unique():
    _df = df.loc[df[cat_field] == cat]
    len_cat = len(_df)
    for field in fields:
        try: # If your field contains integrer or float
            null_count = _df[field].value_counts()[int(null_value)]
        except IndexError: # If it contains text (string)
            null_count = _df[field].value_counts()[str(null_value)]
        except KeyError: # There is no null value
            null_count = 0
        not_null_count[field][cat] = len_cat - null_count
```

Concerning joining the results to the input table without more information, it's complicated to give you an exact answer that will meet your expectations (because there are multiple columns, so it's unsure which value you want to add).

EDIT:

Here is some additional code following your clarifications:

```py
# Create a copy of the table
copy_name = '' # name of the copied table
copy_path = gdb_path + '\\' + copy_name
arcpy.Copy_management(input_table, copy_path)

# Dividing copy data with summary
# This step doesn't need to convert the dict (not_null_value) to a table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(copy_path, [cat_field] + fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        category = row[0]
        for i, fld in enumerate(field):
            row[i+1] /= not_null_count[fld][category]
        cur.updateRow(row) 

# Save the summary table as a csv file (if needed)
df_summary = pd.DataFrame(not_null_count)
df_summary.index.name = 'Food Area' # Or any name
df_summary.to_csv('path/to/file.csv') # Change path

# Summary to ArcMap Table (also if needed)
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion('path/to/file.csv',
                              gdb_path,
                              'name_of_your_new_table')
```

Comment: Hi Paulloed, many thanks for your answer it was really helpful and sorry for not responding for so long, I was dragged off on another project so couldn't work on this. I managed to get this working but I now have an output in 'not_null_count' in the following format: {'field1': {u'category1': 10, u'category2':5, u'category3': 7}, 'field2': {u'category1': .... etc.. Would I be able to turn this into a table and join it to the input table using the category (and where 'field1', 'field2' etc were added as columns to the table)? Thanks again and let me know if you need more info

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired output is.
 [Something like this ?](https://ibb.co/vLpQ27R) (image hosted on ImgBB)

Comment: To make it a bit easier to explain, I'm looking at several different food types and the number of locations (points) that they are produced in various areas. So what I need is column 1 to be the area name (and each area name will only occur once in this column) then column 2 will be food type 1, col 3 will be food type 2 etc and these will show the number of points that food is produced in each area. In my array at the moment I have {'food_type1': {u'area1': a, u'area2': b, ....}, 'food_type2': {u'area1': a, u'area2': b,....} and so on where 'a' and 'b' are the number of food production points

Comment: To me, you are looking for a summary table and don't really need to join the non null data to your existing table. Is this what you want: https://ibb.co/yPg7xgB ?

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I want (except with several more columns for each food type)

Comment: I should add that I need to then perform calculations on the original input table using the results from this summary table - I need to divide the food production values in the input table by the number of food production points in each specific zone/area.

Comment: I update the answer following your clarifications. Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks like what I need. I'll give it a go in the next day or two and let you know how I get on. Thanks for all your help

Comment: If the answer meet your needs, please valide it :)